# Confusion about the quotient space appearing in the statement of Killing Hopf Theorem

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

Here is the statement of Killing Hopf Theorem in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Killing%E2%80%93Hopf_theorem):

> Complete connected Riemannian manifolds of constant curvature are isometric to a quotient of a sphere, Euclidean space, or hyperbolic space by a group acting freely and properly discontinuously

I'm a little confused about what this means in practice, perhaps due to a confusion about quotient spaces. Is this just saying that if I start with a manifold of constant curvature then I can apply an isometry and get one of the three space forms?

Comment: It's not an isometry, but a covering map. Any space form (complete manifold of constant sectional curvature) is covered by a $\mathbb{S}^n$, $\mathbb{E}^n$, or $\mathbb{H}^n$.

Comment: What is the significance of that? On p24 of https://arxiv.org/pdf/2003.11180.pdf it seems to be arguing that if I have a space form with negative curvature, I can assume that I have $\mathbb{H}^n$. And then I can rescale the metric such that this $\mathbb{H}^n$ has $K=-1$ and I have a "hyperbolic manifold". Does that sound right? If so, can you elaborate on how the covering allows me to assume that the space form is $\mathbb{H}^n$?

Comment: The author there adds "simply connected" to the definition of a space forms, which excludes all but the three model spaces $\mathbb{S}^n$, $\mathbb{E}^n$, and $\mathbb{H}^n$. All non simply connected space forms are *locally* equivalent to one of the model spaces, since covering maps are local isometries. Consider as examples the torus $\mathbb{T}^n$ with a flat metric, which has zero sectional curvature, or the .real projective space $\mathbb{RP}^n$ with a round metric, which has constant positive sectional curvature.